# Regression kriging of binomial data

Tags: r, gstat, kriging

I use gstat to predict a binomial data, but the predicted values go above 1 and below 0. Does anyone know how I can deal with this issue? Thanks.

```
data(meuse)
data(meuse.grid)
coordinates(meuse) <- ~x+y
coordinates(meuse.grid) <- ~x+y
gridded(meuse.grid) <- TRUE

#glm model
glm.lime <- glm(lime~dist+ffreq, meuse, family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(glm.lime)

#variogram of residuals
var <- variogram(lime~dist+ffreq, data=meuse)
fit.var <- fit.variogram(var, vgm(nugget=0.9, "Sph", range=sqrt(diff(meuse@bbox\[1,\])^2 + diff(meuse@bbox\[2,\])^2)/4, psill=var(glm.lime$residuals)))   
plot(var, fit.var, plot.nu=T)

#universal kriging
kri <- krige(lime~dist+ffreq, meuse, meuse.grid, fit.var)
spplot(kri[1])
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, with this kind of regression kriging approach there is no guarantee that the model will be valid as the calculation of the trend and the residuals is separated. A few notes on your code. Notice that you use `variogram` to calculate the residual variogram, but `variogram` uses a normal linear model to calculate the trend and thus also the residuals. You need to determine your residuals from your `glm`, and then calculate a residual variogram based on that.

You could do this manually, or have a look at the `fit.gstatModel` function from the `GSIF` package. You could also have a look at [`binom.krige`](http://hosho.ees.hokudai.ac.jp/~kubo/Rdoc/library/geoRglm/html/binom.krige.html) from the `geoRglm` package. [This thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2008-February/003175.html) on R-sig-geo might also be interesting:

> Taking residuas from a GLM is rather different from using indicator
>   variables. Also there may be even some differences depending on which
>   kind of GLM residuals you take. Run a GLM and exploring the residuals
>   e.g. via variograms, is something I consider a routine practice, but
>   it does not aways tell you the whole story. Fitting a GLGM
>   (generealised linear geostatitical model) can be more conclusive since
>   you can do infereces on the model parameters and access the relevance
>   of the spatial term more objectively. This was the original motivation
>   for geoRglm doing all the modelling at once and not by two steps such
>   as fitting a model without correlation and then modelling residuals.
>   This came with the extra burden of calibrating the MCMC algorithms.
>   Later spBayes came to scene and indeed looks promissing proposing a
>   more general framework whereas geoRglm is rather specific to
>   univariate binomial and poison models.
>
> As Roger says there is scope to play around with other alternatives
>   like the GLMM or maybe MCMCpack, but this is certainly not ready
>   "out-of-the-box" and code will need to be adapted for spatial
>   purposes.